# How do I get a tighter grid for MIDI editing in GarageBand 10?

Tags: macos, garageband

In the previous versions of garageband, when I double-clicked on a region and the editing window on the bottom popped up, I could use the ruler button to choose how tight the quantize grid was.

In a 2016 update I don’t find this control in the same place.

How can I change that timing  grid now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can!  But the feature is different than before.  To get a smaller grid you can click the arrow at the right side beat/tempo/key led area and select "time".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[You can't.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5544245?tstart=0) Apparently GarageBand is either hiding the option or it no longer exists.